# Find the time the music sound starts

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have this sound file where I am looking for the time the music starts. I am limited to using only the scipy module. How do I detect the time on x axis when the sound starts?

An example figure is shown below. The Signal with higher magnitudes shows when the music.

Note sometimes there is noise in the signal which could also have high peaks.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create single signal

dt = 0.001
t= np.arange(0,6,dt)

lowFreq =  np.sin(2+ np.pi*10*t)

musicFreq =  3.5*np.sin(2+np.pi*25*t)
combinedSignal = np.concatenate([lowFreq,musicFreq])
plt.plot(combinedSignal)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample image1]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the time when the sound start by just using:

```
idx_start = np.where(combinedSignal > 1)[0][0]
```

This will return the first index where the magnitude of your signal is greater than 1.